# Formatting string to get just words in a column

Tags: java, string-formatting, file-writing

I have a text:

```
c:\MyMP3s\4 Non Blondes\Bigger!\Faster, More!_Train.mp3
```

I want to remove form this text these characters: `:,\!._`
And format the text then like this:

```
c
MyMP3s
4
Non
Blindes
Bigger
Faster
More
Train
mp3
```

And write all of this in a file. 
Here is what I did:

```
public static void formatText() throws IOException{

    Writer writer = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("File.txt")));

    String line = "";
    while(br.readLine()!=null){
        System.out.println("Into the loop");

        line = br.readLine();
        line = line.replaceAll(":", " ");
        line = line.replaceAll(".", " ");
        line = line.replaceAll("_", " ");

        line = System.lineSeparator();
        System.out.println(line);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("Write.txt")));
        writer.write(line);
    }
```

And it doesn't work!

The exception:

```
 Into the loop
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Application.formatText(Application.java:25)
    at Application.main(Application.java:41)
```

Comment: Did you mean `line += System.lineSeparator();`?

Comment: Can you please post what the output of the program was?

Comment: @PM77-1 I will write the output

Comment: Please don't place your program output on the comments but [edit] your question and add the information there

Comment: You do not need to create new `writer` object for every line you write.

Comment: For better help sooner please post a valid [mcve]

Comment: Keep in mind that the first parameter to [replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is not simply a string, but a string that represents a regular expression (regex). "." has a [special meaning in regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html), so it needs to be escaped with a "\".

Comment: @Frakcool ok thank you, I will.

Comment: @mangotang Thank you! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your code, you have:

`line = System.lineSeperator()`

This resets your replacements. Another thing to note is [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) takes in a regex for the first parameter. So you have to escape any sequences, such as `.`

```
String line = "c:\\MyMP3s\\4 Non Blondes\\Bigger!\\Faster, More!_Train.mp3";
System.out.println("Into the loop");

line = line.replaceAll(":\\\\", " ");
line = line.replaceAll("\\.", " ");
line = line.replaceAll("_", " ");
line = line.replaceAll("\\\\", " ");

line = line.replaceAll(" ", System.lineSeparator());

System.out.println(line);
```

The output is:

```
Into the loop
c
MyMP3s
4
Non
Blondes
Bigger!
Faster,
More!
Train
mp3
```